# how to display the same value into another class's textfield?

Tags: iphone

hi all i have implemented code as shown in the below here problem is when i clicked on click event textfield *settextvalue value is not appearing into the next view textfield for this give me the solution in iphone.

ClassA.h

```
@classB
{
    UITextField *settextvalue;
    ClassB *b;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)UITextField *settextvalue;
@property(nonatomic,retain)ClassB *b;
@end

ClassA.m
{
@ synthesize b,settextvalue;

-(void)viewDidload{

   b = [[ClassB alloc]init];
   settextvalue.text=@"333";
}
-(IBAction)resultOfvalue{

       [self.view addSubview:[b view]];

         settextvalue.text = b.resultyear.text;




}



Class B.h {

UITextField *resultyear;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)UITextField *resultyear;
@end

Class B.m
{
@synthesize resultyear;
}
```

Comment: give the code in proper format, its not readable

Comment: Please learn how to format your question(and code you have posted) to make it readable. This looks really ugly..! **Please post questions with proper format**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your property is

```
@property(nonautomic,retain)UITextField *resultyear;
```

It Should be

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)UITextField *resultyear;
```